# JavaScript Image object

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me how I can access the following line of HTML in JavaScript, please? I cannot seem to find the image object in JavaScript:

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="5"><img src="../image/6765.jpg" width="330" height="130" />
```

The end result is that I want to change the images. Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your `<img>` element a unique `id`:

```
<img id="myImage" src="../image/6765.jpg" width="330" height="130" />
```

Then in JavaScript you should be able to get a reference to your element with `document.getElementById()`:

```
document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'new-image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

or ... hunt for it's occurrences (0,1,2 or more x) ...

```
javascript:
    for(i in document.images)
        if(/\/image\/6765\.jpg/.test(document.images[i].src))
/* resolve the base address with the '..' for a more stringent test */
             alert([ 'image URI found at image index: ', i,
                      '\n\nimage.src is\n', document.images[i].src ])
```

For instance looking for '.jpg' or '.png' or '.gif' on this page itself

```
javascript:
    for(i in document.images)
        if(/\.(jpg|gif|png)/.test(document.images[i].src))
             alert([ 'image URI found at image index: ', i,
                      '\n\nimage.src is\n', document.images[i].src ])
```

finds:

> image URI found at image index: ,0,
>
> image.src is
>   ,http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/c9180f024ecb4880954922ef7a72be87.gif
>    
>    
>    
>    
>   image URI found at image index: ,4,
>
> image.src is
>   ,http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/2568.jpg
>    
>    
>    
>    
>   image URI found at image index: ,6,
>
> image.src is
>   ,http://sstatic.net/ads/img/careers2-ad-header-so.png